# OpenGL ES 2.0, What's the range of Varyings?

Tags: ios, opengl-es

In my Vertex Shader, I created :

```
attribute vec2 a_varytest;              
varying  vec2 v_varytest;
```

and set the value:

```
v_varytest=a_varytest;
```

In my Fragment Shader, I created:

```
varying  vec2 v_varytest;
```

The problem is:

When I set the value of attribute "a_varytest" between 0.0 and 1.0 in my main application, the interpolating  works fine.
But When I set it to 10.0, I get a black scene. It seems Varyings in fragment shader can not bigger than 10.0, or the interpolating  won't work.

I test the value of the varying v_varytest. It is always be 2.0. So, It seems when value of a Varying is bigger than 10.0, the interpolating  won't happen, and the value is set to 2.0 automatically.

Someone tell me the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason, i have:

```
precision lowp float;
```

in my code, so the precision of float is only 8 bytes.

I commented that line, it works again.